# Replace elements in an array by element from another array on PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I need to replace some elements in an array with elements from another array but I dont know the structure on powershell.

For instance I have:

```
$A = @("t","o","p")
$B = @("u","g","j")
```

I want `t` to become `u`, `o` to become `g`.

I guess you need to use a `Foreach` and create a loop but I'm not sure at all about the syntax.

By the way I'm working on XML data how do you save the changes on the active folder?

Comment: I am afraid you are gonna get some downvotes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Hi, thanks, ... are considered noise](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950);

Comment: Welcome as a new user, you should take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to replace all the elements in `$A` to the corresponding ones in `$B`, why not just do `$A = $B`.

If there is some sort of condition, use something like this.

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $($B.Count); $i++)
{
    if ("Insert Conditon here")
    {
        $A[$i] = $B[$i]
    }
}
$A
```

All of this happens in the memory. And this is not XML format. Since you mentioned some folder, use the `out-File` cmdlet to save to disk. I dont know what else to tell you. Not enough information.